# How to deal with company name?

Tags: android

I tried to get the contacts' company name but all examples I found are based on Contacts data structure and not on ContactsContract one.

I found an example which was supposed to work with this code:

```
                // Get Organizations.........

                String orgWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
                String[] orgWhereParams = new String[]{id,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
                Cursor orgCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                            null, orgWhere, orgWhereParams, null);
                if (orgCur.moveToFirst()) {
                    String orgName = orgCur.getString(orgCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.DATA));
                    String title = orgCur.getString(orgCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TITLE));
                }
                orgCur.close();
```

Unfortunately, when I execute this code, orgName contains the phone number and not the company name.

Is there anybody familiar dealing with this "strange" organization information ???

Regards,

Comment: the company name is in the ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.COMPANY column.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I already tried that field also and cannot find anything in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found it thanks to "http://www.cnblogs.com/lycoris/archive/2011/05/13/2037716.html" code. that not a problem about the access field:

The correct way to initialize the cursor is:

```
Cursor cCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
              null,
               ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID
               + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?",
               new String[] { id, 
               ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE },
                                    null);
```